# Where does Jenkins keep downloaded files?

Tags: file

I am not able to find the downloaded files in my system. It is not there in download folder.
Files are downloaded through Jenkins and I am unable to find the location of downloaded files.
I have used chrome settings as well but that did not work.
Can anyone help me on this issue. Thanks in Advance.